# I want SweetAlert popup to stay on the same page when I click outside the popup but it navigates to another page

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

**when I click on the done button of the popup it navigates to another page. I want it to stay on the same page when I click outside the popup  but it navigates to another page**

import swal from "sweetalert";

```
swal({
        title: "Good job!",
        icon: "success",
        button: "Done",
        type: "success",
      }).then(() => {
        history.push("/email_template");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.then`

```js
swal({
  title: "Good job!",
  icon: "success",
  button: "Done",
  type: "success",
});
```